# How do I evaluate$ \iint_D (x+2y)^2 e^{x-y}dxdy$ , where $D$ is the region in the $x-y$ plane bounded by a parallelogram?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

The vertices of the parallelogram are $(0,0), (1,1), (2,-1)$ and $(3,0)$
I was integrating the equation for $y = x$, and $y= \frac12x + 3$ and I realized this might need a "change of variables".
So how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we let $A=(0,0)$, $B=(1,1)$, $C=(2,-1)$ and $D=(3,0)$. Then, the equations of the lines of the parallelogram are $\overline{AB}:x-y=0$, $\overline{AC}:x+2y=0$, $\overline{BD}:x+2y=3$ and $\overline{CD}:x-y=3$. This suggests making the change of variable $u=x-y$ and $v=x+2y$ (so that the bounds of the resulting double integral are constant). Can you continue?

You might find the following inverse transform useful for computing the Jacobian:
$$x=\frac{2u+v}{3},\quad y=\frac{v-u}{3}$$

Comment: Thank's I got it! I was unsure about how to make the transformation but I just substituted x and y into each other. Is that the right way to do it?
Essentially in the end, the region became a square and the integrand became a lot easier to compute!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by substituting $x$ and $y$ into each other, but if you want to integrate a function $f(x,y)$ over a region $D$, and then are given the transformation $x=g(u,v)$ and $y=h(u,v)$, then the region becomes $D^*$ and the integral becomes:
$$\iint_D f(x,y)~dx~dy=\iint_{D^*} f(g(u,v),h(u,v))\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|~du~dv$$
Where $\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}$ is the Jacobian determinant. So in our specific case, the integral becomes:
$$\iint_D (x+2y)^2 e^{x-y}~dx~dy=\int_0^3 \int_0^3 v^2 e^u\cdot \frac{1}{3}~du~dv$$

Comment: But yes, you are right that the region becomes a square, and the integral is much easier to compute. What answer do you obtain?

Comment: I'm still confused about how you arrived at the bounds of the interval?